# Printing a table in a blade using a 2D array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am returning a 2D array with the following structure. I couldn't print the values using foreach loop in the usual manner. How can I iterate over the array so that it will print the data i.e. days in the first column and the categories in the other columns?

Thank you in advance

Array structure

[image: Array Structure]

table Structure

[image: Table Structure]

Comment: what do you mean by `I couldnt print the values using foreach loop in the usual manner.` ? you do not want to use forloop or you caould not figure out how to loop through the array ?

Comment: @KamrulKhan i tried with for each but couldnt get the expected result. so basically now i am in  a situation that i couldnt figure out how to print the data in the expected manner

Comment: ok, can you please show us a print_r() of you array rather than the image that you have added ?

Comment: @KamrulKhan i got this from dd() method inside laravel controller. I just snipped it as an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
@foreach ($data as $date => $array)
    {{ $date }}
    {{ $array['Electrical'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given error pops up. And also i need the row values respectively that is say for a particular date , the other columns in that row must be printed according to the table structure electrical,electronics ,lights etc. But according to this I think it only prints to Electrical part.?

Comment: If you get this error that means you've posted wrong data structure in your question. Regarding other fields, just use same syntax as with Electrical for every field.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
@foreach ($data as $date => $array)
    {{$date}}
    @foreach ($array as $item)
        {{$item}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

That way, you are iterating over each element in the associative array that uses the date as the index, then iterating over each item in the array of data that it is pointing to :)